# r matching string data by column and rows

Tags: r

I'm trying to match two columns of string data where one column has more than the other.

Current data look like:

```
df <- data.frame("var1" = c('x','a', 'y','b','c','d', 'z'), 
                       "var2" = c('x', 'y', 'z', '', '', '', ''))
df
   var1 var2
1    x    x
2    a    y
3    y    z
4    b    
5    c    
6    d    
7    z
```

And I would like the row orders in var2 to match var1 where values are the same, but be filled with `0` when they don't match as follows:

Desired output:

```
df

  var1 var2
1    x    x
2    a    0
3    y    y
4    b    0
5    c    0
6    d    0
7    z    z
```

What would be the most efficient way to go about doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: Just so you know, they will be filled with `"0"` as a character string, not `0` the integer/numeric.

Comment: good to know. thanks!

Comment: With dplyr, `df %>% mutate_all(as.character) %>% mutate(var2 = ifelse(var1 %in% var2, var1, '0'))` ...though `NA` is probably safer than `"0"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new variable based on if `var1` is within `var2`

```
library(data.table)
dt = setDT(df)
dt[var1 %in% var2, var3 := var1][is.na(var3), var3 := "0"]

dt
#   var1 var2 var3
#1:    x    x    x
#2:    a    y    0
#3:    y    z    y
#4:    b         0
#5:    c         0
#6:    d         0
#7:    z         z
```

Or use `ifelse`:

```
dt[,var2 := ifelse(var1 %in% var2, var1, "0")]
dt
#    var1 var2
# 1:    x    x
# 2:    a    0
# 3:    y    y
# 4:    b    0
# 5:    c    0
# 6:    d    0
# 7:    z    z
```

*Data*:

```
df <- data.frame("var1" = c('x','a', 'y','b','c','d', 'z'), 
                 "var2" = c('x', 'y', 'z', '', '', '', ''), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: your first one seems to work best as the second one is filling values with integers.  Thanks!

Comment: If your original columns are factor variable, it would end up to be integers. Convert it to character variable should avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R` methods for this

```
v1 <- with(df,var2[ match(var1, var2)])
df$var2 <- replace(v1, is.na(v1), 0)
df$var2
#[1] "x" "0" "y" "0" "0" "0" "z"
```